# Why is there only one segment in .COM programs, both for the program code and for the stack?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I am studying the difference between an .EXE program and a .COM program.
The .EXE is logical to me that the stack is in another segment with respect to the program code (in fact a stack is forced and to indicate a limit of this with .STACK), therefore, when I go to insert values ​​in the stack (in an .EXE), using a different segment than the program, I'm not going to confuse these two.

Example:

```
SP = 0400
SS = 3996 CS = 3995 IP = 0000
```

The stack has a capacity of 1024 Byte (400h) and refers to the stack segment 3996h, which is different from the code segment which is 3995h. So I'm sure the data doesn't get confused.

The thing I don't understand though is when I have to deal with .COM programs; because I know very well that they use only one segment and I find myself with a situation similar to this:

```
SP = FFEE
SS = 114A CS = 114A IP = 0100
```

I have the stack segment which matches the code segment. So if I keep putting values ​​on the stack, will they end up in my code sooner or later?

Comment: Yes, the stack will eventually collide with your code segment.

Comment: While I can only speculate while the COM format only supports a single segment, I suppose it's (a) because this model allows you to treat the 8086 as 16 bit machine, ignoring all segment registers and (b) because back when DOS 1 was released, the IBM didn't come with more than 64k memory in any of the usual configurations anyway and that much memory was seen as pretty outrageous.

Comment: @fuz ["*it existed for backward compatibility with CP/M. CP/M ran on the 8080 processor which supported a maximum of 64KB of memory*"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200728-00/?p=104012)

Comment: @GSerg: Could such programs [automatically translated from 8080 to 8086](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6500/the-start-of-x86-intel-8080-vs-intel-8086) plausibly use SI, DI, or BX to hold pointers to stack memory?  If so, then yeah it would be necessary to use a "tiny" memory model.  As well as having that as a useful feature for code written for 8086 in the first place, not having to futz with segment registers to pass a DS:DX pointer to stack memory to a DOS call or something.

Comment: @GSerg DOS 1 only supported COM-type executables, so I don't think this was purely a matter of compatibility.

Comment: "So if I keep putting values ​​on the stack, will they end up in my code sooner or later?"  Of course, given how 8086 segments worked, this might happen even if the stack segment were not the same as the code segment, if they overlap.  Which they typically would because who would ever need a full 64K for the stack alone?

Comment: This was kind of the whole idea, a simple small model, less complicated, simpler/smaller code etc.  The as you wanted/needed bigger more complicated models you could.  (note the name of this site, stackoverflow).  yes there are simple models where everything shres the same memory space and they can very much collide if you are lazy in your programming.

Comment: @Fuz: I believe the only version of DOS that didn't have support was IBM PC-DOS 1.0 which was basically a rebrand of the latest 86-DOS at the time). 86-DOS didn't support the EXE file format (except for the fact that later on the company that made 86-DOS ended up with an OEM MS-DOS 1.25). The MSDOS releases started at 1.24 which supported EXE file format. 1.24 became the basis for IBM PC-DOS 1.1 (So IBM PC-DOS 1.1+ supported EXE). MS-DOS numbering didn't start at 1.0 since they continued the numbering scheme of 86-DOS. CP/M-86 didn't support EXE format either.

Comment: The other OEM versions by COMPAQ, ZENITH etc were based on MS-DOS v1.25 but they were usually branded with a 1.1x numbering scheme (similar to IBM starting at 1.1x).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While MS-DOS does set all the segment registers to the same segment on program entry after loading a COM file, there's nothing stopping you from changing the registers to use different segments.  However the hard separation between segments you're envisioning doesn't really exist.  Even with a separate stack segment, if you overflow your stack you'll still be writing to memory somewhere you shouldn't be and the results will be unpredictable.

Using your second example of CS:IP being 114A:0100 and SS:SP being 114A:FFFE, your COM program could change SS:SP to 210A:03FE.  Both SS:SP values would point to the same linear address (2149E) and the same return value that MS-DOS pushed on the stack on entry.  You would now only have 1024 bytes for the stack, like in your in EXE example, but your stack segment is still 64k.  In real mode, segments are always 64k.

Now guess what happens when SS:SP is 210A:0000 and you try to push a word onto the stack?  The CPU doesn't generate an exception, it doesn't somehow refuse to perform the operation, it just does what it always does. It subtracts 2 from SP and then stores the word at the new SS:SP address. In this case that means SP will wrap around to FFFE and the value you push will be stored at 210A:FFFE or at a linear address of 3109E.

Now the question is what is allocated at linear address 3109E?  Chances are that MS-DOS allocated this memory to your program and writing values there is harmless since your program isn't using it for anything.  However there's a chance that some TSR or driver has allocated the memory there and overwriting it will cause a crash or other unpredictable behaviour.

**It would actually be better if you overwrote your own code when the stack overflowed as this would mean you'd be much more likely to notice the bug and fix it.**

The same wrap around problem also exists with EXE's.  If you want a truly isolated stack you'd need to make 64K in size, but then what happens on overflow is that the stack overwrites itself so doesn't fundamentally eliminate the problem.  Ultimately it's your responsibility as a developer to ensure that your program has allocated itself enough stack space and that your code never exceeds that limit.

---

Note that there's one stack related gotcha you need to worry about with COM files, and that is there's no guarantee that MS-DOS will be able to allocate a full 64K for your COM file.  MS-DOS will allocate the biggest free chunk of memory that your COM file will fit into.  If that chunk of memory is less than 64K then SP won't be set to FFFE, instead it will set SP to point to the last word allocated to your program.  In the worst case that means the stack will immediately start overwriting the code and data in your COM file.  For that reason it's a good idea to allocate space at the end of your COM file to reserve space for the stack.

Answer (score 0):

A *.com file can resize the ram with function 4ah to the minimum of the executable and finaly to get free ram from DOS with function 48h.